# Skipped frames! On xamarin while loading 225 copy of one image

Tags: image, memory, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm loading one image, 225 times and each of them will have it's own property, On Xamarin Forms...

*It's something like a map*

I have this error while running the code

```
Skipped 376 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My image is 0.5 KB

I run the code when the page loads ...

And the code :

```
        int leftNum = 0;
        int topNum = 1;
        int squareSide = 15;
        for (int i = 0; i < squareSide;i++ )
        {
            mapGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            mapGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++)
        {
            MapNormal[i] = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.Fill };
            MapNormal[i].Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Funema.Resources.Square.png");
            mapGrid.Children.Add(MapNormal[i], leftNum, topNum);


            leftNum++;
            if (leftNum == squareSide)
            {
                leftNum = 0;
                topNum += 1;
            }

        }
```

Is it the correct way to do that ?

EDIT: MY UI CODE AFTER CHANGES

```
namespace XXX
{
    public partial class TestMap : ContentPage
    {
        public TestMap()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            Grid mapGrid = new Grid();

            TapGestureRecognizer[] tapSquareArray = new TapGestureRecognizer[400];
            CachedImage[] mapSquareArray = new CachedImage[400];

            int leftNum = 0;
            int topNum = 1;
            int squareSide = 15;
            for (int i = 0; i < squareSide;i++ )
            {
                mapGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                mapGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++)
            {
                mapSquareArray[i] = new CachedImage()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    DownsampleToViewSize = true,
                    TransparencyEnabled = false,
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                    TransformPlaceholders = false,
                };
                mapSquareArray[i].Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Funema.Resources.Square.png");


                int copy = i;
                tapSquareArray[i] = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapSquareArray[i].Tapped += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Tapped Image : " + copy);
                };
                mapSquareArray[i].GestureRecognizers.Add(tapSquareArray[i]);

                mapGrid.Children.Add(mapSquareArray[i], leftNum, topNum);

                leftNum++;
                if (leftNum == squareSide)
                {
                    leftNum = 0;
                    topNum += 1;
                }

            }

            ScrollView mapScroll = new ScrollView();
            mapScroll.Content = mapGrid;
            mapScroll.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both;

            this.Content = mapScroll;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try ffimageloading for Caching the image and not load 255 images into the memory. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms/

Comment: Again  Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. @Rohit

Comment: It should be fine. Check back if you are facing any performance issues.

Comment: That is because you are adding it one by one.

Comment: @Rohit any ways to add all of them once ?
Cause I show the grid content at the end of the code in the scroll view :  `ScrollView mapScroll = new ScrollView();
            mapScroll.Content = mapGrid;
            mapScroll.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both;
        
            this.Content = mapScroll;`

Comment: Can you add your UI code?

Comment: @Rohit Added complete code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create 400 Images, you are having the same image and properties, only your gesture action might be different I suppose. If that is the case use one image object and add it to a 400 Layout like a frame. You can add the different tap gesture to the layout. According to FFLoading that would have only 1 image in your memory as you are re using the image object.

- You can also try to use Downsampling properties of FFImageLoading, so that the memory consumed by the image is less.
- Another problem is you are doing all your UI heavy task in the Constructor of the page. It is always better to keep your constructor code small. Even to navigate to this page or initially load this page all the code in the constructor needs to be executed.

In your case it would be better for you to only create the Grid in your constructor.

```
public partial class TestMap : ContentPage
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        Grid mapGrid = new Grid();
        for (int i = 0; i < squareSide;i++ )
        {
            mapGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            mapGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
        }
        ScrollView mapScroll = new ScrollView();
        mapScroll.Content = mapGrid;
        mapScroll.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Both;

        Content = mapScroll;
}
```

And then in your `OnAppearing()` or any other event you can call your method to load the children to the grid as an async/await method by even running it in a separate task.

Only the `mapGrid.Children.Add(mapSquareArray[i], leftNum, topNum);` needs to be run on the UI/Main thread ([Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/)), rest can be executed in a background thread. So that your UI thread isn't blocked.

```
private async void LoadGridChildren()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 225; i++)
    {
        mapSquareArray[i] = new CachedImage()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            DownsampleToViewSize = true,
            TransparencyEnabled = false,
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            TransformPlaceholders = false,
        };
        mapSquareArray[i].Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Funema.Resources.Square.png");

        int copy = i;
        tapSquareArray[i] = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapSquareArray[i].Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Tapped Image : " + copy);
        };
        mapSquareArray[i].GestureRecognizers.Add(tapSquareArray[i]);

        //Run on UI thread
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => mapGrid.Children.Add(mapSquareArray[i], leftNum, topNum));

        leftNum++;
        if (leftNum == squareSide)
        {
            leftNum = 0;
            topNum += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of calling from another event (you will have to handle the logic for if already children added):

```
protected overide OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    //run on a separate thread
    Task.Run(() => LoadGridChildren());
}
```

Comment: This line generates an error : `private async LoadGridChildren()` :   

The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry I missed a `void`. You can read about `async` and `await` here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I also tried void myself but again an error `Value cannot be null.` On Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ...

Comment: You can also try - `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { mapGrid.Children.Add(mapSquareArray[i], leftNum, topNum); });` Check more on it at - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/

Comment: Value can't be null will be the code inside your `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` check if any of it is null and why.

Comment: Unfortunately when I use `Task.Run(()=> LoadGridChildren());` I get error on the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` line  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: view . But when I delete task.run and use LoadGridChildren function normally then It runs slowly but with no error @Rohit

Comment: i also missed a `base.OnAppearing();`, did you add it?

Comment: Yes I also added it myself as I said When I delete `Task.Run(() =>` then it works...  @Rohit

Comment: `Task.Run` was only if it was taking too much time and you get the frames skipping error. If it works without that then it is fine.

Comment: Yes but it is extremely slow without task.run, Slower than my old code...

Comment: You can check by setting a Task.Delay to give the UI time to load before you try to add newer items.

Comment: Thank you for your solution ... But still slow and Task.Run generates error

Comment: Task.Run runs everything on a background thread, where you can't update any UI elements from. So you can not use both Task.Run and BeginInvokeOnMainThread